# Endpoint not found issue when giving large data as input

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, web-config

Seem to run into a service endpoint not found problem when trying to get from my service. This happens when I am giving large data as input.

Below are the bindings

**Client Side web.config bindings**

```
<binding name="MyMtomHttp" sendTimeout="23:59:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" transactionFlow="True" receiveTimeout="23:59:00">
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
   <security mode="Message">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
   </security>
</binding>

<endpoint address="http://localhost:58164/Sample.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyMtomHttp" behaviorConfiguration="LargeData" contract="MyService.ISample" name="MyMtomHttp">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LargeData">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Server Side web.config bindings**

```
<behavior name="SampleBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10000" maxConcurrentSessions="10000" maxConcurrentInstances="10000" />
  <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
</behavior>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyMtomHttp" sendTimeout="23:59:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" transactionFlow="True" receiveTimeout="23:59:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SampleBehavior" name="MyMtomHttp">
    <endpoint name="MyMtomHttp" bindingConfiguration="MyMtomHttp" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://Sample/" contract="MyService.ISample">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I have tried all the solutions which are possible including using `maxRequestLength`. But still I am getting the same endpoint not found error.

Below is the exact error message:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:58164/Sample.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690451/wcf-exists-and-partially-working-but-for-some-calls-returns-no-endpoint-listeni) post...

The solution was to add this to web config:

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204800000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Share the exact exception you're getting.

Also, can you refer to these two posts and see if it helps...

- [Endpoint not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897620/endpoint-not-found-wcf-web-service)
- [Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340038/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-413-request-entity-too-large/15383928#15383928)

Comment: I have updated the exact error message in the question.